# How to programmatically start a new virtual machine?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a code that is not thread safe (is using static fields). I want to run it in many threads. the code is doing some parsing of websites. I know I can refactor it, but I don't want to do it now. I would like to run every thread in a new virtual machine. I know I can do it using "java package.class -cp ...", but I have a lot of dependencies. I also cannot use maven "mvn exec:java " since it doesn't support java8.

Is there any way to programmatically start a new virtual machine ?

P.S. I don't want to refactor my code now

Comment: *"I also cannot use maven "mvn exec:java " since it doesn't support java8."* => maven does support Java 8...

Comment: How are you starting your VM now? Use that

Comment: This sounds like a task for a Test. Would you like to write a Integrationtest?

Comment: You dont need to start new VM. New ClassLoader for each thread will be enough.

Comment: You already named the in-Java solutions. Using standard APIs there’s only [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp15956) left. But I recommend trying the suggested `ClassLoader` approach first.

Comment: To elaborate on the class loader approach, what you want is an arrangement where all the dependencies (which are thread safe) are loaded as normal, but you load the non-thread safe library by hand with a class loader that is chained to your application class loader. This way all the dependencies are loaded only once but you can have as many copies of your class with static fields as you want. This is several orders of magnitude more efficient than the external process solution.